# Angular reactive form radio loop checked condition not working

Tags: angular

I want to set a pre-select value for the radio input depending on the condition, but it's not working with me, it is not selected. I am using reactive forms.

`[checked]="uploadname === item.name"`

Could you please assist:

```html
<form class="p-4" [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div *ngFor="let item of products;let x = index">
    <input
      formControlName="productName"
      (change)="getProductDetails(item,item.name)"
      class="radio-label hidden"
      type="radio"
      id="{{'itemid' + x}}"
      [value]="item.name"
      [checked]="uploadname === item.name"
    />
    <label class="button-label" for="{{'itemid' + x}}">
      <img [src]="item.images[0].img" />
      <p>{{item.name | translate}}</p>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is .ts file

```js
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  products;
  productName;
  product: Product;
  uploadname = '';
  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private ProductsListService: ProductsListService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
    private route: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let str = this.router.snapshot.params.product;
    this.uploadname = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    this.products = this.ProductsListService.productItems();
  }
  uploadForm = new FormGroup({
    productName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
  onSubmit() {
    console.warn(this.uploadForm.value);
  }
  get uf() {
    return this.uploadForm.controls;
    console.warn(this.uploadForm.controls);
  }
  getProductDetails(item: any, name: string): void {
    this.product = this.ProductsListService.productDetails(name);
    console.warn(this.product.size);
  }
}
```

Comment: share your .ts file code

Comment: @RaviAshara Post updated, sorry I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how angular reactive forms work, if you want to set preset values to your form, you actually need to set the value to the `formControl` instead.
`checked` in template will be overridden by the form control value, which in your case is an empty string `''`. So, when you get the value for `this.uploadName`, you can use `setValue` to set the value for the form control:

```
this.uploadForm.get('productName').setValue(this.uploadname);
```

Comment: np, glad I could help :)